# Javascript: getSeconds("00") - 3 = 57 sec

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, time

I want to make  code to execute a task 3 seconds before a given time.

Something like this:

```
var Time = new Date('December 25, 1995 08:00:00:000');
Time.getSeconds() - 3 ;
```

This should give me 57, instead of -3

Comment: 1. Modify the date to be 3 seconds earlier 2. Get the seconds. 3. Done

Comment: If you get the seconds of `08:00:00`, it's `00`. If you subtract 3, the result is `-3`. Makes sense, doesn't it? Why should `0 - 3` give `57`?

Comment: Because if its 08:00:00am, -3 sec = 07:59:57 :)

Comment: You are not subtracting 3 from `08:00:00am`. You are subtracting 3 from `Time.getSeconds()`, which is `0`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to *set* the seconds via the the dedicated method first - the logic to handle such “rollovers” is already implemented in there - and then you *read* it again:

```js
// var Time = new Date('December 25, 1995 08:00:00:000');
// careful with the above date format, not all browsers will parse this correctly
// modified version, for this example:
var Time = new Date('1995-12-25T08:00:00');
Time.setSeconds( Time.getSeconds() - 3 );
console.log(Time.getSeconds());
```

Comment: Should work [better than this](https://i.imgur.com/lajk92i.png) if the date was valid. [Demo](https://jsbin.com/vatonay/1/edit?js,console)

Comment: @VLAZ yes, good point. Fabio, the date format used in the initial example does not work in all browsers - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results